# How do I get rid of the white space between elements of my page?

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues getting rid of white space between my navbar and my divs.  I am already using normalize.css and I have tried taking margin and padding away from every element on the page. I've also tried  !important and it had no effect. I'm sure this is an easy fix and i'm just Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
/*General*/
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*Navigation*/
 nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
}

li {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li:hover {
    color: #d6d6d6;
}

/*iPhoneX*/
.iphonex {
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dboauovcs/image/upload/c_scale,w_1200/v1520573356/iphonex_fwlohj.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

/*iphone 8*/

.iphone8 {
    background-image: url("http://res.cloudinary.com/dboauovcs/image/upload/c_scale,w_1200/v1520573369/iphone8_zx2ckf.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Apple Home Page - CSS Grid</title>
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!--Navbar-->
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><i class="fab fa-apple"></i></li>
                <li>Mac</li>
                <li>iPad</li>
                <li>iPhone</li>
                <li>Watch</li>
                <li>TV</li>
                <li>Music</li>
                <li>Support</li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-search"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    
    <!--Full width Iphone X img-->
    <div class="iphonex">
        <h1>iPhone X</h1>
        <h5>Say hello to the future.</h5>
    </div>
    
    <!--Full width Iphone 8 img-->
    <div class="iphone8">
        <h1>iPhone 8</h1>
        <h5>A new generation of iPhone.</h5>
    </div>
    
    <!--1/2 width HomePod img-->
    
    <!--1/2 width Apple watch img-->
    
    <!--1/2 Ipad pro img-->
    
    <!--1/2 Imac pro img-->
    
    <!--1/2 airpods img-->
    
    <!--1/2 enviormentally friendly img-->
    
    
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried running your snippet in full page, I can't seem to see any white space between the navigation and the next `div`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Tried here - https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/VXwBxq. Could you please provide a codepen link and specify the browser and device in which you are facing the issue.

Comment: I agree with the others. I am not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just tried it on codepen and it's working great. I'm using a chromebook and cloud 9. I haven't run into this issue before and i've been running this set up for a few years.

Comment: Do you have a live page someone can take a look at?

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue by removing normalize css. Thanks everyone for the help!